# Write(2) doesn't print to stdout

Tags: c

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

char buffer[BUFSIZE];
int readBytes;
struct termios saved;
struct termios modif;

void onExit(){
  if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &saved) == -1)
    readBytes = readBytes; //placeholder
}

void nonCanonMode(){
  if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &saved) == -1)
    readBytes = readBytes;
  if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &modif) == -1)
    readBytes = readBytes;
  modif.c_iflag = ISTRIP;
  modif.c_oflag = 0;
  modif.c_lflag = 0;
  if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &modif) == -1)
    readBytes = readBytes;
  atexit(onExit);
}
void readChar(){
  int counter = 0;
  readBytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFSIZE);
  if(readBytes == -1)
    readBytes = readBytes;
  while(counter < readBytes){
    if(buffer[counter] == '\004'){
      exit(0);
    }
    else{
      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[counter], sizeof(char)) == -1)
        readBytes = readBytes;
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[counter], sizeof(char));
    }
  counter++;
  }
}
int main(){
  nonCanonMode();
  while(1)
    readChar();
 exit(0);
}
```

The `readChar()` function doesn't print out characters as they are typed in. I put my terminal into noncanonical mode and loop this function indefinitely to read a character at a time. However the function only writes to stdout once. If I comment out the second `write` then there's no output.

Comment: maybe you should [`fsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync)  ?

Comment: Your use of `^D` and the term `terminal` suggest you may want to add what OS you are using.

Comment: I have to use specific system calls. :\

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what OS I'm on but I think it's redhat. I'm sshed into my school's linux server because they have the proper environment set up.

Comment: @usr2564301 The presence of `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` indicates that `<unistd.h>` have been included, and it's a POSIX specific header file. So either macOS or Linux or one of the BSD variants.

Comment: Maybe you should post a [MCVE].

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause this code not to print.  (It has several other problems, though.)  When I compile and run it (under MacOS), each key I type immediately prints twice.  So whatever's causing it not to print as you expect is due to something strange in your environment that we can't see.  Are you sure you're running the code exactly as posted?

Comment: @SteveSummit That's exactly the problem. There are 2 write statements in the else part of readchar but there is only one output. If you comment out the second one there is no output even though there is a write inside the if condition. The immediate output is expected because nonCanonMode() sets the terminal to read without waiting for newlines.

Comment: Blowing away `c_iflag`, `c_oflag`, and `c_lflag` like that is unusual and may be causing you problems.  And you probably don't care about `c_iflag` and `c_oflag` at all.  I recommend leaving `c_iflag` and `c_oflag` alone, and turning off just the `ECHO` and `ICANON` bits in `c_lflag` like this: `modif.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);`

Comment: Also, although its not causing your immediate problem, you should think of something better to do on error than to set `readBytes` to what it already is.

Comment: @SteveSummit I can't make those changes. It specified to do it that way in my project spec. I have an error handling function but it's not important to recreating the problem.

Comment: It sounds to me as if your project spec is wrong.  But since your code works for me, and since you're not even willing to try my suggestions to make it work better for you, there's no way I can help you. Good luck.

Comment: @gj13 he is not using any of the `f*` functions, so no, `fflush` won't help.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu linux.  I opened a terminal window and ran the posted code.  Then I modified the code to not have the second call to `write()`  It worked correctly in both conditions.  Suggest it has something to do with your server or the way your attaching to the server.